# BASHRC PS1 show datetime but plus 3 hours

Tags: bash, escaping, command-substitution, ps1

Every of us set own convenience working with Linux shell, for example I use
/root/.bashrc

```
PS1='[\h:\w] \D{%F %T}\n\$ '
```

to show servername + current server datetime + newline for command - so it looks like

```
[servername217:~] 2022-02-06 00:55:02
#
```

But I met a stumbling block with syntax trying to set not server time, but my home, for example plus 3 hours. It's easy to make with regular BASH

```
date -d '+ 3 hour' '+%F %T'
```

but when I try to use, for example,

```
PS1='[\h:\w] [date -d '+ 3 hour' '+%F %T']\n\$ '
```

I always get an error. It seems PS1 understands only

```
\D{%F %T}
```

but how to add 3 hours to %T under this format ? Or there is an another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
PS1="[\h:\w] \$(date -d '+ 3 hour' '+%F %T')\n\$ "
```

Comment: Thx, it works, exactly what I was asking about.

Comment: Is it possible to start newline without $ sign ? just a clear new line

Comment: This might help: `PS1="[\h:\w] \$(date -d '+ 3 hour' '+%F %T')\n"`

Comment: Yes, of course, I had to guess myself :) thx

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit too heavyweight to use the external `date` command. If you have **Bash 4.3+** you can use the builtin `printf %(fmt)T`:

```
$ cat ps1
NOW_PLUS_3_HOURS=''

function _prompt_command()
{
    local secs

    printf -v secs '%(%s)T'
    (( secs += 3 * 3600 ))
    printf -v NOW_PLUS_3_HOURS '%(%F %T)T' $secs
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=_prompt_command
PS1='[$NOW_PLUS_3_HOURS] $ '
$ date +'%F %T'
2022-02-06 16:37:02
$ source ./ps1
[2022-02-06 19:37:06] $
[2022-02-06 19:37:11] $
```

And by using the `PROMPT_COMMAND` you can do a lot more interesting things.

Comment: Thx, very interesting to try with PROMT_COMMAND based on your script, but if talking about PS1 - another answer is more direct to question. Anyway - very useful.

Answer (score 2):

For bash v4.2 or higher, you can use the `printf` date format specifier. This should be more efficient than forking a new `date(1)` process at each prompt:

```
PS1='[\h:\w] $(printf "%(%F %T)T" "$((\D{%s} + 60*60*3))")\n\$ '
```

Personally, instead of a command substitution in `PS1`, I prefer to set a variable with `PROMPT_COMMAND` (a string which executed before each prompt), and use that in `PS1`. This makes it easy for example to unset `PROMPT_COMMAND` if the command is causing trouble.

That can be done like this (bash 4.3 or higher required for `printf "%(%s)T"` to print the current date):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
ps1_date=$(printf "%(%F %T)T" \
"$(($(printf "%(%s)T") + 60*60*3))"
)'
```

Or this (bash 4.4 or higher required for `${ps1_date@P}`):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
    ps1_date="\D{%s}"
    ps1_date=${ps1_date@P}
    ps1_date=$(printf "%(%F %T)T" "$((ps1_date+60*60*3))")'
```

Then just use that variable here:

```
PS1='[\h:\w] ${ps1_date}n\$ '
```